# Does listening to a stream using Provider works same as listening once in initState() without the Provider

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider, stream-builder

From the state changes point of view and firebase cost, does using

```
data = Provider.of<MyModel>(context);
```

Or maybe Consumer() in build method, with a StreamProvider.
works same as

```
@override
  void initState() {
  data = readDataFromFirestore(); // Listening my Stream here and using in build method
  super.initState();
}

static Stream<MyModel> readDataFromFirestore() async* {
  // stream code here
}
```

and then use StreamBuilder in build method.

What if we have multiple listeners of same stream. What is the best practice from firestore cost and optimisation point?

Comment: I understand provider is optimal in terms of rebuilding widget & there are properties like updateShouldNotify to build widgets for custom needs. For understanding firebase cost point of view, need more clarity on how it works, especially FutureProvider and StreamProvider.

Comment: I have searched through articles on internet but could find what I need at one place.